# How does growth in the number of nonisomorphic groups tells us something about the number of ways subgroups can be put together?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

On page 104, Dummit and Foote discusses the extension problem and makes the following remark:

> Part (2) of the Hölder Program, sometimes called the extension problem, was rather
> vaguely formulated. A more precise description of "putting two groups together" is:
> given groups A and B, describe how to obtain all groups G containing a normal subgroup
> N such that $N\cong B$ and $G/N\cong A$. For instance, if $A = B = Z_{2}$, there are precisely
> two possibilities for G, namely, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $V_{4}$ (see Exercise 1 0 of Section 2.5) and the
> Hölder program seeks to describe how the two groups of order 4 could have been built
> from two $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ without a priori knowledge of the existence of the groups of order 4. This
> part of the Hölder Program is extremely difficult, even when the subgroups involved
> are of small order. For example, all composition factors of a group G have order 2
> if and only if $|G|=2^{n}$ , for some n (one implication is easy and we shall prove both implications in Chapter 6). It is known, however, that the number of nonisomorphic groups of order $2^{n}$ grows (exponentially) as a function of $2^{n}$, so the number of ways of putting together groups of 2-power order together is not bounded.

I do not understand how do they conclude that 'number of ways of putting together groups' is not bounded.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, I've added a bit more of the quote to give context. However, I am not sure what work needs to be included.  Like, I simply do not see the logical link between the premises and the conclusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find this statement a bit vague. I guess it means something like if $N$ and $M$ are finite $p$-groups, then there is no absolute bound on the number of isomorphism classes of groups $G$ with a normal subgroup $K \cong N$ and $G/K \cong M$. Any such bound is a function of $|N|$ and $|M|$.

That is really not surprising. What is more impressive is the rate of increase. Graham Higman proved that if $N$ and $M$ are elementary abelian of orders $p^{n/3}$ and $p^{2n/3}$, then there are at least $p^{2n^3/27 + O(n^2)}$ possible $G$.

Comment: At the risk of sounding childish, may I ask why is the rate impressive? I am too novice in group theory to be able to appreciate this right away.

Comment: @Jaspreet It tells us that the number of groups of order $p^n$ is  "about" $p^{2n^3/27}$, which is generally regarded as being an impressively large number. (The upper bound was proved later by Charles Sims and has since been improved, but the point is that $2n^3/27$ iss the principal term in the exponent.)